# Javascript, Pannellum: Overlay image captures mouse/touch events

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, pannellum

I have built a panorama using Pannellum and placed an image above it. Now the problem is that mouse and touch events are applied to the image and do not reach the panorama viewer in order to control it. I can imagine a solution by placing a transparent panorama above all so that the mouse events control it. Then place the real pano below all and mirror the movements to it. Is there a better solution? I've read about event bubbling but didn't understand it yet.

Comment: There's nothing in this question that anyone can work with.  Please read [ask] and provide an [mcve].

Comment: Unfortunately my question is a bit complex and cannot be compressed into a few lines of code. My question is: Is there a solution to place an overlay image above a pannellum viewer and still be able to control the image by dragging the mouse. The problem is that in this case the mouse events are captured by the image and do not reach the viewer.

Comment: Then put more than a few lines of code in.  Your question has few views, no comments and no votes because there is *nothing to work with*.  You need to make a visible attempt to answer this yourself before most people would be willing to put any effort in to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable interactions with the image by using the css option

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Just add it to the style-tag of your image.

Example with an canvas in a div:

HTML

```
<div id="crosshairCont"><canvas id="crosshair" height="450px" width="800px"></canvas></div>
```

CSS

```
#crosshairCont{
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}
```